# Article , section html5 semantics

Tags: html, css, semantics

I'm a little confused about article VS Section in HTML 5.

My web page is divided into different types of foods.
Each row is a different type of food -  (Meat, veg and desserts). Each row is subdivided into three columns / recipes

Should I enclose everything in a section tag AND then each type of food (row) in and article tag?

```
<h2> Vegetable recipes </h2>

<div class="row_divider clearfix>
    <div class="span1_of_3>
        <p> a veg recipie1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3>
        <p> a veg recipie2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3> 
        <p> a veg recipie1 </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end row-->

<h2> Meat recipes </h2>

<div class="row_divider clearfix>
    <div class="span1_of_3> 
        <p> a Meat recipe 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3> 
        <p> a Meat recipe 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3> 
        <p> a Meat recipe 3 </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->

<h2> Dessert recipes</h2>

<div class="row_divider clearfix>
    <div class="span1_of_3> 
        <p> a Dessert recipe 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3>
        <p> a Dessert recipe 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1_of_3>
        <p> a Dessert recipe 3 </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

Comment: from you're description it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve. But from my experience, no (they're used for something different than this).

Answer (score 2):

No you should not wrap each item in `<article>` see on [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article)

In case you have a list of items you should wrap each one in `<li>` - list item and wrap all of those with `<ol>` or `<ul>` depends if the order of the items is important.

Comment: Ok, thanks, just to clarify ... maybe I can wrap each row in a section and then each individual recipe in an article ? Therefore for each row (section) will have three articles